# Can I prevent a component from rendering on certain paths in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

So I'm using react router dom for routing in react and have been trying to render a certain component on every path with a few exceptions for example the component can render on all paths except **/login** and **/signup**, I tried using the location props provided by BrowserRouter to check if it's those paths and not render but it gives me an unexpected result, please I would like to know if there is a way to achieve this? Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Waht's the unexpected result, can you post the error message here as well.

Comment: You can just not put that component in the Route or you can add an additional Boolean prop, and using a ternary operator, render null and not the actual content of component, when you route to than specific path, you can either pass the prop directly or through history.push()

Comment: @Asutosh sorry apparently my route component was outside a switch and I was using an logic or rather than a logic && for the check, I've fixed the problem, thanks for the effort :)